# Help with Uitextfield

Tags: cocoa-touch

Hey .... im working on a Iphone app ..i cant get this working:

i want this alert to show up if the text field is empty when clicking the button linked to "timedAlarm" and if the text filed has a text i want it to go ahead and do the local notification,  every thing works fine, until i put in this code before all the code for the notification, i have tried a lot of ways, but it wont work, either the alert shows up, even if there is a text, or els the alert wont show.

```
- (IBAction) timedAlarm {

    if (eventText.text != nil){

        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Excuse Me !" 
                                                          message:@"Plz enter an alarm text" 
                                                         delegate:nil 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil]; 

        [message show]; 

        [message release]; 

    }else {
```

Hope u can help me :-D

Rene Skov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you show alert if text is entered in textfield (i.e. text property is not nil), so you need to reverse condition you have. Additionally you may want to check if current text is an empty string (user might enter some text and delete it afterwards - in that case text will not be nil).

```
if (event.text == nil || [event.text length] == 0){
   // Show alert
}
else{
  // Text is ok
}
```

Comment: I guess the second condition will suffice, since nil will return 0 for length.

Comment: @Eiko, agree, may be it's my bad habit to do this redundant check

Comment: Nor worries, I also do this often... most of the time when porting Java or C++ code. And sometimes it helps readability.